# Request from external party is not captured by the WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, .net-4.0, sap

I have a SOAP WCF service hosted in IIS and it is consumed by another company SAP system and everything was working fine for couple of years until our security team implemented Header validation in request.

It stopped working all of sudden since the client SAP system request doesn't contain header `CallingType`. So then they added `CallingType` and pushed request to our system and F5 server allowed access and request entered to our system where WCF hosted.

But WCF did not logged request and no data we got. So I would like to know how I can troubleshoot and provide fix. My network team is telling request is validated and passed by F5 server and pushed to our server.

But why WCF is not logging anything?? Do I need to add any custom header in `webconfig` of WCF service, or our IIS is preventing something? How can I see the way IIS is blocking the request?

Comment: Have you set up Request Filtering in iis? You can first use F12 to check the network in the browser, or you can try to use failed request tracking to view detailed request information, and you can also debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool. this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: DO i need to custom header in webconfig of wcf.I have added extra logging in webconfig and going to test.I